# Jinja2: splitting a string into multiple lists

Tags: python, jinja2

I would like to take an input string such as

```
"server1:port1,server2:port2,server3:port3"
```

and split it into 2 lists:

```
servers = [ server1, server2, server3 ]
ports = [ port1, port2, port3 ]
```

there are two delimiters to split by here: first it's ",", and then the elements themselves are split by ":".

is there a quick way to do this?

also, how to "toString" any of the lists into something like
portString="port1,port2,port3" ?

Comment: thank you guys for the answers in Python. much appreciated!  for now I need the Jinja2 solution more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do this in your jinja template, then you can use the following code.

```
    {% set server = [] %}
    {% set port = [] %}
    {% set x= "server1:port1,server2:port2,server3:port3" %}
    {% for i in x.split(',') %}
        {% for j in i.split(':') %}
            {% set server = server + j[0] %}
            {% set port = port + j[1] %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

But its a very bad idea to do this in template. Its better if you pass it as a dictionary to your template and then use it like this

```
{% for k,v in x.iteritems() %}
#use k as server and v as port
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension and `join` function to achieve this.

```
>>> a ="server1:port1,server2:port2,server3:port3"
>>> temp = [i.split(':') for i in a.split(',')]
>>> temp
[['server1', 'port1'], ['server2', 'port2'], ['server3', 'port3']]

>>> servers = [i[0] for i in temp]
>>> ports = [i[1] for i in temp]
>>> servers
['server1', 'server2', 'server3']
>>> ports
['port1', 'port2', 'port3']
>> ','.join(ports)
port1,port2,port3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the desired output:

```
def denormalize_addr_str(addr_str):
    return reduce(lambda denorm_list, addr: denorm_list + addr.split(':'), addr_str.split(','), [])

addr_str = "server1:port1,server2:port2,server3:port3"

denorm_addr_str = denormalize_addr_str(addr_str)
servers = denorm_addr_str[::2]
ports = denorm_addr_str[::-2]
port_string = ','.join(ports)
```